# compile libgssapi_krb5.a static library for Centos 6

Tags: linux, centos6

our software depends on the availability of statically linking with this library.  Our research indicates it is no longer available as a yum package in centos6.  How can we go about compiling this, and other static libraries for krb5?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Download krb5 source from http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/index.html to `/usr2/krb5testing/krb5-1.11.1`, then execute

```
cd /usr2/krb5testing/krb5-1.11.1
./configure CFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32 --prefix=/usr2/krb5testing/krb5-1.11.1/binary --build=i686-redhat-linux --enable-static --disable-shared 
make
cd lib
cp libgssapi_krb5.a /usr/lib/.
cp libkrb5.a /usr/lib/.
cp libk5crypto.a /usr/lib/.
```